# Memory leak in MySQL C++ Connector

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-connector

I am using MySQL C++ connector. Valgrind is showing it is leaking 192 bytes on every connection. 
It is leaking memory only in threaded environment without threading it is not leaking any memory.What I am doing wrong ? Do I need to call some other functions for cleanup ?
Sample code:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cppconn/driver.h>
#include <cppconn/exception.h>
#include <cppconn/resultset.h>
#include <cppconn/statement.h>
#include <cppconn/prepared_statement.h>

using namespace std;

void* test(void* arg) {

  try {
    sql::Driver *driver;
    sql::Connection *con;
    /* Create a connection */
    driver = get_driver_instance();
    con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "root");
    /* Connect to the MySQL test database */
    con->setSchema("test");
    delete con;
  } catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
    cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
    cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line " << __LINE__ << endl;
    cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
    cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
    cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << endl;
  }
  return NULL;
}

int main() {
  pthread_t thread1, thread2, thread3, thread4;
  pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, test, NULL);
  pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, test, NULL);
  pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
  pthread_join(thread2, NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

Valgrind output:

```
==10252== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==10252== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==10252== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==10252== Command: ./app/bin/app-test
==10252== Parent PID: 6312
==10252== 
==10252== 
==10252== HEAP SUMMARY:
==10252==     in use at exit: 384 bytes in 2 blocks
==10252==   total heap usage: 212 allocs, 210 frees, 208,400 bytes allocated
==10252== 
==10252== 192 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 2
==10252==    at 0x4C29DB4: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==10252==    by 0x5E1CB3E: my_thread_init (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0)
==10252==    by 0x5E1CE3C: my_thread_global_init (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0)
==10252==    by 0x5E1AA54: my_init (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0)
==10252==    by 0x5DF86CA: mysql_server_init (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0)
==10252==    by 0x4EA3C08: sql::mysql::NativeAPI::getCApiHandle(sql::SQLString const&) (in /usr/lib/libmysqlcppconn.so.5.1.1.0)
==10252==    by 0x4EA40EA: sql::mysql::NativeAPI::MySQL_NativeDriverWrapper::MySQL_NativeDriverWrapper(sql::SQLString const&) (in /usr/lib/libmysqlcppconn.so.5.1.1.0)
==10252==    by 0x4EA4138: sql::mysql::NativeAPI::createNativeDriverWrapper(sql::SQLString const&) (in /usr/lib/libmysqlcppconn.so.5.1.1.0)
==10252==    by 0x4E6F2F3: sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver::MySQL_Driver(sql::SQLString const&) (in /usr/lib/libmysqlcppconn.so.5.1.1.0)
==10252==    by 0x4E6F50B: sql::mysql::get_driver_instance_by_name(char const*) (in /usr/lib/libmysqlcppconn.so.5.1.1.0)
==10252==    by 0x40AB8C: test(void*) (main.cc:17)
==10252==    by 0x50D9E99: start_thread (pthread_create.c:308)
==10252== 
==10252== 192 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 2
==10252==    at 0x4C29DB4: calloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==10252==    by 0x5E1CB3E: my_thread_init (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0)
==10252==    by 0x5DF86DC: mysql_server_init (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0)
==10252==    by 0x5DFE85E: mysql_init (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18.0.0)
==10252==    by 0x4EA4A82: sql::mysql::NativeAPI::MySQL_NativeConnectionWrapper::MySQL_NativeConnectionWrapper(boost::shared_ptr<sql::mysql::NativeAPI::IMySQLCAPI>) (in /usr/lib/libmysqlcppconn.so.5.1.1.0)
==10252==    by 0x4EA4014: sql::mysql::NativeAPI::MySQL_NativeDriverWrapper::conn_init() (in /usr/lib/libmysqlcppconn.so.5.1.1.0)
==10252==    by 0x4E6F0DC: sql::mysql::MySQL_Driver::connect(sql::SQLString const&, sql::SQLString const&, sql::SQLString const&) (in /usr/lib/libmysqlcppconn.so.5.1.1.0)
==10252==    by 0x40ABE8: test(void*) (main.cc:18)
==10252==    by 0x50D9E99: start_thread (pthread_create.c:308)
==10252==    by 0x5AFCCBC: clone (clone.S:112)
==10252== 
==10252== LEAK SUMMARY:
==10252==    definitely lost: 384 bytes in 2 blocks
==10252==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10252==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10252==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10252==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10252== 
==10252== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==10252== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
```

Comment: Not knowing diddly about mysql, the dump from valgrind in relation to your code suggests the leak is the driver instance, but it is possible this is being stashed in TLS and kept for caching.  I'd be curious to see what would happen with that code in a loop (i.e. 10 calls per thread) which would be trivial for you to test.

Comment: @WhozCraig How to free driver_ memory. It's destructor is private?

Comment: @VivekGoel I am facing same issue. Can you please provide details how did you solve this?

Comment: Apart that you're program will have a leak whenever exception happens in the try...catch block, `driver` usage is wrong.
You need to have a global variable for driver and call `get_driver_instance()` only once from `main()`. Don't call delete on `driver` nor try to free it somehow, it's an embedded structure which should live until your program exits.
When using threads, in each new thread **you must** call `driver->threadInit();`. _After_ your thread has finished using MySQL and _before_ your thread terminates  **you must** call `driver->threadEnd();`.

Answer (score 4):

as WhozCraig suggested you can add  `delete Driver;` to your test function but i would suggest using `auto_ptr` or the C++11 `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` for everything MYSQL and you will never have to worry about memory leaks

take this for example

with C++11

```
std::unique_ptr< sql::Connection > con( driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "root"));
```

or the C++

```
std::auto_ptr< sql::Connection > con( driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "root"));
```

**EDIT**

you can't just `delete Driver` , i will look into it more when i have the time

**UPDATE**

I looked through the `driver.h` source code, it is indeed `protected:
    virtual ~Driver() {}` so you can't just use a delete, how ever in `public:` there are two

```
virtual void threadInit() = 0;

    virtual void threadEnd() = 0;
```

which may be what you need

there is also this [example](http://mysql-connector-cplus-pplus-p.sourcearchive.com/documentation/1.1.0-1/pthreads_8cpp-source.html) which may be very useful and does this a bit differently then you

Comment: If I try to delete drive object I gets following error. virtual sql::Driver::~Driver()’ is protected

Comment: i did some digging we use this in production no `delete driver` in our code but in the docs and our code there is a `con -> close();` before `delete con`

Comment: if you just add a deconstructer to the for the driver it solves the problem

Comment: I am facing same issue but couldn't get solution you provided. It's bit confusing how to add deconstructor for the driver? You mean to derive another class from Driver or how else?

Answer (score 1):

First problem is that your code is wrong. In case of any exception in `try` block, program will never reach `delete con;` statement and you will be left with open connection to MySQL server and memory leak. You have to declare and delete `con` outside the `try` block or use C++11 smart pointer:

**Wrong:**

```
  try {
    sql::Connection *con = driver->connect("URL", "user", "password");

    // code

    delete con;
  }
  catch (const sql::SQLException &e) {
    // code
  }
```

**Correct, before C++11:**

```
  sql::Connection *con = NULL;     
  try {
    con = driver->connect("URL", "user", "password");

    // code

  }
  catch (const sql::SQLException &e) {
    // code
  }
  delete con; // delete on NULL is harmless.
  con = NULL;
```

**Correct, C++11, recommended way:**

```
  try {
    // unique_ptr will automatically call delete when it goes out of scope.
    // That will also happen in case of exception.
    std::unique_ptr<sql::Connection> con (driver->connect("URL", "user", "password"));     

    // code

  }
  catch (const sql::SQLException &e) {
    // code
  }
```

Also, `driver = get_driver_instance();` should be called only once in your program, not in every thread. So you should make `sql::Driver *driver;` a global variable and call `driver = get_driver_instance();` in `main()` before you create any threads.

Answer (score 0):

I also get a Valgrind warning. You cannot change MySQL++, but it's possible to limit the problem to 0 or 1 leak. For me, I have ONE class with 1 thread that handles all the SQL-communication for sync/async messages using a thread-safe queue on top.

For every message, I have a class with semaphore, callback function, type, message-id. The id is used in logging.

Also, all re-entrant problems may be solved, since not all mysql implementations are thread-safe.

If people are interested, I'll put this code on sourceforge. It's proven to work, because it's used in many dutch restaurants in Linux POS software with MySQL5.7. Also I checked it with valgrind.