# MySQL Prepared Statements not cleaning up in an infinite loop using C++ Connector

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-connector

I'm writing a program which updates MySQL tables every few seconds as new data is received. The function has an infinite loop to update constantly, with another loop inside it that iterates through table rows and picks data accordingly.

Unfortunately, no matter what I do, I encounter the most pathetic error:

> Can't create more than max_prepared_stmt_count statements

I've tried simply deleting all mysql related values (except con and driver) after each iteration with statements [seen in the example code here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-examples-complete-example-1.html).

I've tried adding

```
 stmt = NULL;
 stmt->close();
```

Just in case before every value.

I've tried rewriting the program with [auto_ptr](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-tutorials-stored-routines-prepared-statement-out-parameter.html), which allegedly clean up automatically, based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13334837/8439299) answer.

I have even tried closing and reestablishing connection to the MySQL server after each iteration, but even that did not help me.

Please help.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a pathetic error, the limitation is there so your memory doesn't run out or to mitigate denial of service attacks. You can always increase the limit, but 16,382 connections seems a lot even for a persistent application.

Comment: I meant that it felt pathetic getting it

Comment: Oh right, yes error codes can be condescending!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More information on your loop may be required.

But it sounds like your `stmt = con->createStatement();` is inside your loop. You only need one connection, before your loop starts.

Then you can execute a statment multiple times in your loop, `res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT 'Hello World!' AS _message");`

When your application terminates then you close your stmt, `delete stmt;`

From mysql.com "The default value is 16,382."  [mysql.com-sysvar_max_prepared_stmt_count](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_prepared_stmt_count) Which it sounds like you only require one.

Comment: I am trying this right now! While I wait for it to crash or not crash, one more question - will it work with prepared statements? If I declare the statement before the loop, and then use setInt/setString/etc. before each executeQuery(), will it take in the new values and run with them?

Comment: I'll test it myself eventually, for now, this actually worked, and improved performance tenfold. Thank you for this, I've just been bashing my head against the wall..

Comment: Glad it worked, sometimes you just need someone outside to see the issue. I haven't used C++ in years so I can't give specifics, but mysql works mostly the same in different languages. In saying that, you should be able to prepare it outside of the loop, and execute it in the loop, that is how it was intended to function.